# Are software recommendations in-topic or not?

Tags: discussion, support, site-scope

I asked a software recommendation:

[Best iPhone app to track stocks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439939/best-iphone-app-to-track-stocks)

This isn't the first time I do it, and my other questions were generally well-received:

- [App which allows me to comment *and* to write free-hand on PDFs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438996/app-which-allows-me-to-comment-and-to-write-free-hand-on-pdfs)
- [Shortcut/app to capture only the content of a window in a screenshot?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341981/shortcut-app-to-capture-only-the-content-of-a-window-in-a-screenshot)
- [App to lock my iPhone for some time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329913/app-to-lock-my-iphone-for-some-time) (closed, but the motivation was

> This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers. Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.

so, apparently this wasn't related to the question being about software recommendations)

- [(preferably) free app to lock iPhone for predetermined periods of time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312611/preferably-free-app-to-lock-iphone-for-predetermined-periods-of-time)

However, my current one already received 2 close votes in less than 1 hour.

1. Are software recommendations for iOS on-topic here or not?
2. If they are *conditionally* on-topic, i.e., it depends on the way the questions is formulated; can you help me reformulate my question better?
3. If they're off-topic, no matter how I formulate the answer, where could I ask the question in the SE hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation) to see what is important and what should be avoided when asking for software recommendation. There is also https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ which focuses solely on software recommendation, please check what is [on topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there and [which minimal standards](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) are expected from questions before posting.

In a nutshell, asking for "the best" app or listing highly subjective criteria like "reasonable price" will increase the likelyhood of getting downvotes or votes to close/put on hold, as does lack of any research on the topic.

PS: Also, if you look at your previous questions, most of them received clarification comments which you only partially addressed, and answers which more often than not didn't actually recommend specific products. Editing questions based on comments received is essential to get good answers though.

Comment: I'm editing my question according to How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?. "Price is generally a poor requirement" seems an unreasonable rule, though - I need an app that literally has to do just **ONE** simple thing more than the free Stocks app, so it's only natural that I don't want to pay for it. However, according to this rule I can't put this constraint in my question. It sounds like more of a rule to make app sellers happy, than a well-though, useful rule

Comment: @DeltaIV Price is a poor requirement because prices will change over time, they also have different meaning for different people. So you may be willing to pay a max amount of 5 for an app offering specific functionality, others may be willing to pay 15. Please keep in mind that good questions and answers usually attract visitors in the future as well.

Comment: Does a price of 0 changes with time? I don't think there's a big track record of apps, _of such a low level of sophistication as what I'm looking for_, that started as free, and then eliminated the free tier later on. Maybe they added some in-app purchase, or some paid-for tier with extra features, but I guess the free tier would still be an option even in the future. Anyway, since I'm not allowed to mention that I'm looking for a free app, I'll keep the requirement to myself.